# Hazelcast - why IMap.remove(key) is blocked? Need forceRemove

Tags: java, integration, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to force remove a key from map upon a management operation. The thread trying to remove is not the one putting ...

The thread is stuck as below..:

```
Thread [xxxx] (Suspended)   
    waiting for: InvocationFuture<E>  (id=1746) 
    Object.wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]  
    InvocationFuture<E>(Object).wait(long) line: 201    
    InvocationFuture<E>.pollResponse(long) line: 300    
    InvocationFuture<E>.waitForResponse(long, TimeUnit) line: 245   
    InvocationFuture<E>.get(long, TimeUnit) line: 222   
    InvocationFuture<E>.get() line: 202 
    MapProxyImpl<K,V>(MapProxySupport).invokeOperation(Data, MapOperation) line: 320    
    MapProxyImpl<K,V>(MapProxySupport).removeInternal(Data) line: 449   
    MapProxyImpl<K,V>.remove(Object) line: 188
```

Why is map.remove() is blocking? Is not there a way to force remove an entry from map?

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map.remove` is lock-aware, which means it will wait until a lock has been released. That is one of the reasons why the method call may not complete immediately.

So question: **Are you using locks?**

If so you can do map.forceUnlock and then call map.remove().
Don't know if it will suit your business use-case though (hard to imagine).

Comment: Yes I am using locks and calling forceUnlock just before remove. Forceunlock documentation says that it always successfully releases the lock but for my case it doesn't make any difference. .. Remove is still blocking for a reason I do not know..

Comment: Any suggestions Tom?

Comment: Are you sure there are no other threads/clients that acquire the lock in-between? (between the forceUnlock and remove)?

Comment: I think you are right.. I guess some other thread waiting in tryLock takes the lock after the  forceUnlock call and this causes me to wait in remove.. This is bad for me but your answer is correct. Thnx

Comment: Good to hear. Thx!